# complete callback is not being called for async.parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to make an api call for 100 rows to populate description (which I prefer to do it in parallel). However some of rows might not have description in this case api will return 404. I need to show a warning message when there are a row or rows without description and remove those rows from modal data which means I need a complete callback or done callback. However the completeCallback is not being called and I "think" it's because some of rows doesn't have description.

Could you please tell me how to achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
    function getDescription(processedData) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseApiUrl + '/Summary?id=' + processedData.id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                processedData.SummaryDescription = data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, e) {
                if(xhr.statusCode === 404){
                    processedData.SummaryDescription = '';
                }else{

                }
            }
        });
    };

//Below line is in a look
parallelCallArray.push(getDescription.bind(null, processedData));

//Below line is out of loop
Async.parallel(parallelCallArray, function(err, result){
  console.log('all calls completed...');
});
```

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json',` — you are making a GET request and are sending no `data`. What are you describing the content type of?

Comment: Good point. I need to remove that. copy-past problem ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the callback parameter of your function(s) that are being executed in parallel. If you don't execute the callback, `async` will assume your functions haven't finished yet. Try something like this:

```
function getDescription(processedData, cb) {
  $.ajax({
    url: baseApiUrl + '/Summary?id=' + processedData.id,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
      processedData.SummaryDescription = data;
      cb();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, e) {
      if (xhr.statusCode === 404) {
        processedData.SummaryDescription = '';
      } else {
      }
      cb(new Error(e));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I need to pass that callback as first parameter of bind?

    parallelCallArray.push(getDescription.bind(function(){
      console.log('calback');
    }, processedData));

Comment: No. `async` calls your functions like `func(cb)` and you've already bound one argument, so the `cb` will be passed as the second argument. So no other changes are needed except to add the `cb` parameter to your function(s).

Comment: Cool. It works. Now the problem is in completeCallback the result object is array[100] but each item is undefined. I need to have processData with appended SummaryDescription. so that in complete callback loop throw it and remove those which doesn't have description. Any clue on that?

Comment: Assuming you want `data` for each successful parallel function, you'd change `cb()` to `cb(data)` in the `success` callback. Then you could probably even remove your `.bind(null, processedData)` altogether, since `processedData` is not a per-function variable anyway.